# How to use Hardware MFT for encoding audio from PCM to AMR in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, audio-streaming, codec, ms-media-foundation

i need to encode my audio PCM raw stream to AMR. but i didn't find anything much regarding that.i need to know is it possible to use Hardware MFT for encoding and decoding the Audio stream. if yes then how it is possible some idea please.

or any other way to encode Audio Stream from PCM raw to AMR codec?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question in Microsoft forum and i got the answer, the answer is Microsoft doesn't support in-build AMR codec, to support AMR codec in windows phone we need to use Third Party Codec Library.

[The response](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/28e2bc65-e938-4256-b8ee-43affe556666/is-it-possible-to-use-media-extension-for-encoding-raw-audio-pcm-data-to-amr-data?forum=wpdevelop) was:

> Unfortunately it doesn't appear that we supply an AMR encoder in box. Because of this you will need to find a 3rd party encoder or use the in box low latency mp4 codec that we do provide.

and then also:

> Let me try and clarify. We have limited AMR, 3GP and h.263 support for Windows Phone Silverlight apps. Encoding support for these codecs is not exposed in Runtime apps since we do not provide a default encoding profile implementation. These codecs should only be exposed in Silverlight. There doesn't appear to be a runtime activateable class associated with these codecs so there is no reflection into Media Foundation.